# How to change format of a function call but keep the input the same

Tags: regex, vim, latex, vi

How can I change in my document all instances of \cite{something} to [@something]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a Find by this RegExp: `\\cite\{([^\}]+)\}`
and Replace by: `[@\1]`

Comment: The complete command would be: `%s/\v\\cite\{([^}]+)\}/[@\1]`

Comment: thank you @Daan, I just wrote the regexes as I'm unfamiliar with vim/latex

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with :

```
:%s#\v\\cite\{([^}]+)\}#[@\1]#g
```

note that the last 'g' flag will be important if you have more than one `\cite{something}` in same line.

Since you want to replace ALL instances, I would do it with 'g'.

Comment: Yes, so should search with 'g' if you dont have `set gdefault` in your settings.